# d3js enter().append after exit().remove()

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a word cloud that can be filtered by date range and sentiment. Sometimes there will be more data sometimes there will be less. When I remove data, update the dom and then add data the elements that were removed won't come back. Using d3js version 3.4.13

---

```js
 var width = 600, height = 200;
    var words = ["Hello", "world", "Wonderful"];
    //inserting text
    var wcwords = d3.select("#wordcloud")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")")
        .selectAll("text")
        .data(words)
        .enter()
        .append("text");

    wcwords
        .attr("transform", function(d,i) {
            return "translate(" + [5, 20*i] + ")";
        })
        .text(function(d) { return d; });
    //changing data and updating dom (in this change there are less items)
    wcwords.data(words.slice(0,2)).exit().remove();
    //changing data and updating dom (in this change there are more items)
    wcwords.data(words.concat(["No"])).enter().append('text')
        .attr("transform", function(d,i) {
            return "translate(" + [5, 20*i] + ")";
        })
        .text(function(d) { return d; });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg id='wordcloud'></svg>
```

---

### EDIT

Original code did not work put updated my post with code that does what I need. New, deleted and updated items animate differently. I can change existing items, delete items and return items again.

The trick was to use the right selection `parent.selectAll(children)` and pass the update object (object returned by `.data(newData)`)

Here is the "working" code, hope I did it correctly:

```js
var width = 600;
var height = 200;
var words = ["Hello", "world", "Wonderful"];
var when=1000;
var step=1;
//this function sets the data and passes the update object
//  to exit, update and enter
function change(data){
  var update =   d3.select('#wccontainer')
    .selectAll('text')
    .data(data);
  exitWords(update);
  updateWords(update);
  enterWords(update);
}
//existing items move to the right
function updateWords(update){
  update
    //this is an existing item, no need for append
    .text(function(d) { return d; })
    .transition()
    .duration(when-100)
    .attr("transform", function(d,i) {
      this.left=this.left+25;
      return "translate(" + [this.left, 20*i] + ")";
    })
    .style('opacity',1);
}
//new items fade in
function enterWords(update){
  update
    .enter()
    .append("text")
    .attr("transform", function(d,i) {
      this.left=0;
      return "translate(" + [5, 20*i] + ")";
    })
    .text(function(d) { return d; })
    .style('opacity',0)
    .transition()
    .duration(when-100)
    .attr("transform", function(d,i) {
      return "translate(" + [5, 20*i] + ")";
    })
    .style('opacity',1);
}
//removed words fade out
function exitWords(update){
  var removeItems = update
    .exit()
  removeItems
    .transition()
    .duration(when-800)
    .style('opacity',0)
    .each('end',function(){
      removeItems.remove();
    });
}
function later(when,fn,parms){
  setTimeout(function(){
    fn.apply(null,parms);
  },when);
}
//create the g container and set svg width/height
d3.select("#wordcloud")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
  .attr('id','wccontainer')
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 
      + "," + height / 2 + ")")
//set the text labels
change(words);
//in 1000ms (value of when) set the text lables with changed data
later(when,change,[words.slice(0,2)]);
//in 2000ms  set the text lables with changed data
later(when*++step,change,[["CHANGED"]
  .concat(words.slice(1,2))
  .concat(["ONE","TWO","THREE","FOUR"])]);
//in 3000ms  set the text lables with the original values
later(when*++step,change,[words]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg id='wordcloud'></svg>
```

Comment: There are a few issues to explain here but first, why would you expect the word Wonderful to be put back? Maybe there is a typo in your code? Should it be ["Wonderful"] instead of ["No"]?

Comment: @CoolBlue Thank you for your reply. I'm trying to make my word cloud animate like this one: https://www.jasondavies.com/wordcloud/#%2F%2Fwww.jasondavies.com%2Fwordcloud%2Fabout%2F
Words can be added, removed and then added again. When I try this though the removed words won't come back.
The example is minimal code demonstrating how I change the data and try to get the elements

Comment: Can you be more specific?  It would be good if you edited your question to show exactly what output you expect... I don't understand what order you want the words to be in at the end for example...

Comment: @CoolBlue I added some more text in my previous comment (accidentally pressed enter) This is for a word cloud where filters are applied to it so sometimes words are changed, removed and added depending on the filter. Now after removing a word and adding words after the elements removed wont come back as the minimal code demonstrates.

Comment: Well... ok... but can you please edit your question with the additional information I mentioned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll first explain what's happening first...

```
var width = 600, height = 200;
var words = ["Hello", "world", "Wonderful"];

var wcwords = d3.select("#wordcloud")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")")
    .selectAll("text")
    .data(words);
    .enter()
    .append("text");
```

wcwords is now an enter selection which happens to have the same structure as the update collection because all elements are new.  Because `selectAll` is used, the selection is nested under the `g` node: this is the parent object of the selection.

```
wcwords
    .attr("transform", function(d,i) {
        return "translate(" + [5, 20*i] + ")";
    })
    .text(function(d) { return d; });

wcwords.data(words.slice(0,2)).exit().remove();
```

All this is doing is use the `data` method as a selector to remove one DOM element.  The new selection (with only two elements) is not referenced in-scope and `wcwords` is *unchanged*, so in fact the DOM is now out of synch with the selection.

```
wcwords.data(words.concat(["No"])).enter().append('text')
    .attr("transform", function(d,i) {
        return "translate(" + [5, 20*i] + ")";
    })
    .text(function(d) { return d; });
```

A new selection is created and again, the `wcwords` object is unchanged.  The node structure of `wcwords` (not the DOM structure) is compared to the new data structure and since there are 3 nodes in the former and 4 in the latter and because `data` preserves indexing, the enter selection will consist of a single group of 4 elements with the first three elements `null` and the final element being the datum object for the new node.  A new text node is then added to the end of the parent node of `wcwords` (the `g`) by the `append` statement.  Since the third element is not in the enetr selection, it is not re-inserted.

The basic principles are that

1. `data` does not change the object it is called on, it returns a reference to a new selection (which is ignored here)
2. the `data` statement compares the *selection* structure to the data structure when constructing the enter, update and exit selections.  It is not compared to the DOM structure.

---

I'm guessing about the order you expect since you haven't shared that but maybe you were going for something like the following.

```js
var width = 70, height = 100;
    var words = ["Hello", "world", "Wonderful"];
    var outputLog = OutputLog("#output-log");
    var transitionLog = OutputLog("#transition-log");

    var wcwords = d3.select("#wordcloud").style("display", "inline-block")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
        .append("g")
        .style("font-size", "10px")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + 10 + "," + 20 + ")")
        .selectAll("text")
        .data(words)
        .enter()
        .append("text")
        .style("opacity", 0);

    wcwords
        .text(function(d) { return d; })
        .attr("transform", function(d,i) {
            return "translate(" + [5, 20*i] + ")";
        })
        .call(step, 0, "in")
        .call(log, "wcwords.data(words) enter");

    // bind a new data set to the selection and return the update selection
    var wcwords = wcwords.data(words.slice(0,2))
        .call(log, "wcwords.data(words.slice(0,2)) update");

    // merge the enter selection into the update selection and update the DOM
    wcwords.enter()
        .append("text")
        .style("opacity", 0);
    wcwords.exit().transition().call(step, 1, "out").remove()
        .call(log, "exit");

    // modify the selection by rebinding the original data
    // but with an extra element concatenated
    // and return the update selection
    var wcwords = wcwords.data(words.concat(["No"]))
        .call(log, "wcwords.data(words.concat(['No'])) update");

    // update the DOM and merge the exit selection into the update selection
    wcwords.enter().append('text')
        .attr("transform", function(d,i) {
            return "translate(" + [5, 20*i] + ")";
        })
        .text(function(d) { return d; })
        .style("opacity", 0)
        .call(step, 2, "in")
        .call(log, "enter");

    function datum(n){
        return n ? d3.select(n).datum() : "";
    }
    function step (selection, s, type) {
        var id = Date.now(),
            opacity = {in: 1, out: 0},
            t = 1000,
            w = 0, b = "";
        selection.each(function(d){w = Math.max(w, d.length) });
        b = new Array(w+4).join('_')
        this.transition(Date.now()).delay(s * t).duration(t)
            .each("start." + id, function(d, i, j){
                var n = this, node = d3.select(n),
                    DOM_node = d3.select(selection[0].parentNode)
                    .selectAll(this.nodeName).filter(function(d){return node.datum() === d});
                DOM_node = DOM_node.length ? DOM_node[0][0] : null;
                transitionLog.writeLine(["start ", (""+id).slice(-4), s, type, (d+b).slice(0,w), style(this, "opacity") || "null", DOM_node === n].join("\t"))
            })
            .each("interrupt." + id, function(d){
                console.log(["\tinterrupt ", id, type, style(this, "opacity"), s].join("\t"))
            })
            .each("end." + id, function(d){
                var n = this, node = d3.select(n),
                    DOM_node = d3.select(selection[0].parentNode)
                        .selectAll(this.nodeName).filter(function(d){return node.datum() === d});
                DOM_node = DOM_node.length ? DOM_node[0][0] : null;
                transitionLog.writeLine(["end", (""+id).slice(-4), s, type, (d+b).slice(0,w), style(this, "opacity") || "null", DOM_node === n].join("\t"))
            })
            .style("opacity", opacity[type]);
        function style(n, a){return d3.select(n).style(a)}
    }

    function log(selection, title){
        outputLog.writeLine(title);
        outputLog.writeLine(this[0].map(datum), 1);
    }

    function OutputLog(selector) {
        var outputLog = d3.select(selector)
            .style({
                "display"    : "inline-block",
                "font-size"  : "10px",
                "margin-left": "10px",
                padding      : "1em",
                "white-space": "pre",
                "background" : "#fd9801",
            });
        outputLog.writeLine = (function() {
            var s = "";
            return function(l, indent) {
                this.text((s += ((indent ? "  " : "") + l + "\n")));
            }
        })();
        return outputLog
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.min.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
<svg id='wordcloud'></svg>
<div id="output-log"></div>
<div id="transition-log"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it helped in understanding what update, enter and exit is. I've updated my question with the working solution and hope it's the correct way of doing things (could merge some copy paste code in functions).

Comment: @HMR your new code is very nice.  It's an important detail that you did the update _before_ the enter so that they will be treated separately, so that's good. My original answer was broken because the version of d3 doesn't support named transitions, but it's fixed now.